# Как создать рамку для Layout?

Tags: java, android

Есть разметка xml для ячейки, которая используется в адаптере для GridView.

Надо создать рамку, например в 1px, вокруг каждой ячейки. Желательно чтобы можно было задать ей цвет.

Ниже разметка для ячейки:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/rl_main"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFE4B5"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_day"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="1dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:text="3"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    >
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_green"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_day"
    android:paddingRight="3dp"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorDarkGreen"
    android:text="34">
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_red"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_day"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_green"
    android:paddingRight="3dp"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorCrimson"
    android:text="56">
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_title_day"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_day"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingRight="3dp"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="56">
</TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно задать бэкграунд для RelativeLayout или еще лучше - поместить все это дело в CardView и работать с ним. 
как вариант для понимания наглядно воспользоваться сайтом , например [энгритулс](http://angrytools.com/android/button/)

и подложить бэкграунд с обводкой `android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"`
В случае с CV аттрибут card_view.

как вариант:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <!--Border width and color-->
    <stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="?attr/colorAccent" />
    <corners
    android:radius="6dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Я написал стили и подгружаю нужный для каждой ячейки. А можно создавать стили программно?

Comment: Применять программно точно можно, создавать, наверняка, тоже. Но я этим не занимался, поэтому не подскажу, увы(